# Pause Parallel.For Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, parallel-processing

I have a nested `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach` loop which will be sending out emails to chunks.  The list could be over 10000 emails long - so I decided to chunk the list into parts and send.  But I would also like to be able to pause after each `Parallel.For` iteration.  I have looked for a way - but got nowhere.

```
if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                List<string> emailList;
                List<string> invalidList = new List<string> { };
                string[] attachments = { };
                if (rbListType.Items.FindByValue("CSV").Selected)
                {
                    emailList = tbEmailTo.Text.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                    int count = 0;
                    int total = emailList.Count;
                    RadRadialGauge1.Scale.Max = total;
                    RadRadialGauge1.Scale.Min = 0;
                    var errorList = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
    var chunk = emailList
        .Select((value, index) => new { Index = index, Value = value })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2)
        .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Value).ToList())
        .ToList();



    Parallel.For(0, chunk.Count, i =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(chunk[i], email =>
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage em = new MailMessage();
                em.From = new MailAddress(tbEmailFrom.Text);
                em.To.Add(email.ToString());

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEmailCC.Text))
                {
                    em.CC.Add(tbEmailCC.Text);
                }

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbEmailBC.Text))
                {
                    em.Bcc.Add(tbEmailBC.Text);
                }

                em.ReplyToList.Add(tbReplyTo.Text);
                em.Body = tbEmailBody.Text;
                em.IsBodyHtml = true;
                em.Subject = tbSubject.Text;
                em.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;
                em.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                SmtpClient sm = new SmtpClient();

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(smtpServer))
                {
                    sm.Host = Host.SMTPServer;
                }
                else
                {
                    sm.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    sm.Host = smtpServer;
                    sm.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
                }

                sm.Send(em);
                Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
            }
            catch (SmtpException smtp)
            {
                errorList.Add(email.ToString() + "<br />");
            }
        });  
     });
```

Comment: Why would you need to pause?  Specially what are you trying to achieve by pausing?

Comment: So I don't overload our email server

Comment: Then why don't you do a non-parallel `for` loop instead?  Also does this actually cause errors when you run it?  You should be limited by the number of threads the thread pool gives you.

Comment: I tried that first - but ran into problems with  the Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

Comment: What kind of problem?

Comment: Did not update the email count

Comment: Threading is being used to I have a valid list of emails sent  vs emails not sent.

Comment: And I am a newbie learning Parallel stuff - lol

Comment: I'd recommand not doing two levels of parallel looping.  First try just a `Parallel.ForEach` over all the emails and test it to see what happens.  You can control the maximum number of thread (and thus the maximum number of emails sent at the same time) with `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = max }`.  As for the count incrementing that should have worked even with only one level of parallel looping.

Comment: Also you might want to consider looking into sending the emails asynchronously as the sending process is IO bound.

Comment: I just think I will choke our email server if there is no pause(time to recover).  My chunking is doing what the MaxdegreeofParallelism is doing  - isnt it?

Comment: And the count only seems to work if I have two levels of parallel looping.  Since I tried a normal for loop first then the parallel foreach.

Comment: As it stands you splitting the emails in to groups of 2 then saying process all these groups in parallel, then inside of that you say process these 2 emails in parallel.  So really you're just limiting it to half the number of emails, though it's likely to use even fewer threads than that.  Best bet is to not fix something that isn't broke yet.

Comment: The 2 will be replaced by a user parameter - just in testing now.

Comment: Where do you define the `count` variable and where do you access it?  You might want to ask a new question about why it isn't incrementing properly.

Comment: On second thought this actually tells it to process all emails in parallel, so it doesn't really limit it, but I guess that's why you want a pause.  The problem is that the pause doesn't stop the next iteration.  Basically you're asking how to make a `Parallel.For` act like a regular `for` because the incrementing isn't working for some reason, so again I think asking why the incrementing isn't working would be the best route to go.

Comment: Posted additional code - it is incrementing properly now.

Comment: I meant if you do a regular `for` loop, but again I think just one parallel loop and maybe setting the maximum number of threads is the way to go, but first test and see if it does overload the email server.

Comment: It is a requirement by the VP - before I go hog wild on the mail server.  This way we could throttle it up and see how it reacts.

Comment: Yeah, definitely use a test server first if you can.